# Can't get my JS to work on a simple link

Tags: jquery, weblinks

I just launched my website  : [https://lise-whales.com/](https://lise-whales.com)

Joomla  3.9.28

Astroid Framework 2.5.2

Astroid Template One 1.3.2

I want to use [Featherlight lightbox](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight) with JS script

So I past before the </head in Astroid custom code area

```
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/featherlight@1.7.14/release/featherlight.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and before </body in Astroid custom code area (see attached picture)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Featherlight -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/featherlight@1.7.14/release/featherlight.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<!-- End - Featherlight -->
```

But before that, I'm trying to understand how use basic JS
I'm working on a basic example from Stackoverflow

On my home page I have this link whick works fine alone and links to my second page

```
<a id="ali" alt="Ali" href="https://lise-whales.com/page-fl">Link</a>
```

Then, when I place my code in the JS custom code of Astroid to make my ID "ali" to change the href to stackoverflow web site, it doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#ali").attr("href","https://stackoverflow.com");
});
```

I also used

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

as an alternative, but it still doesn't work

What I am doing wrong ?

Where should I put my JS code ?

Thanks

Lise

---

Here are the pictures from my Astroid Template Custom Code Area.

[image: Code for Featherlight in Astroid Custom area]

[image: My JS Code]

Answer (score 1):

this is not a full answer by any means, but are you sure the JQuery is working?  I had to use `jQuery('selector')` instead of `$('selector')` to make mine work.

Comment: This is a common solution in Joomla - the $ alias for jQuery clashes with other JS libraries Joomla users, so in the past I've had to often implement jQuery using jQuery('selector') instead of $('selector')

Comment: Thank you.
 Indeed, I should use  jQuery('selector') instead of $('selector') . And I did using : 
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#ali").attr("href","https://stackoverflow.com");
});
I placed it in the JS custom code of Astroid. It didn't work.
I placed it between <script></script> at the end of the article. It didn't work either.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. This is new to me.
I read that I should call JHtml::_('jquery.framework');  ???

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to load jQuery **after** your small script to change the `href` value.

I'm going to suggest simply not using jQuery, as it's pointless for what you need, and instead use simple, native Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('ali').setAttribute('href', 'https://stackoverflow.com');
});
```

If you need IE support:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('ali').setAttribute('href', 'https://stackoverflow.com');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Lodder,**

it works !!!

I used your first native Javascript in the JS custom of Astroid and it worked perfectly

And, regarding your comment on loading jQuery **after** script, I decided to try to place my custom JS in a separate file (monjs.js) that I placed in /media/system/js/ and I called in the head using this script :

```
<!-- Mon JS -->
<script type="text/javaScript" src="/media/system/js/monjs.js"></script>
<!-- End - Mon JS -->
```

I simply placed your script in the file and it works fine as well

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('ali').setAttribute('href', 'https://stackoverflow.com');
});
```

**But**, If I replace it by

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#ali").attr("href","https://stackoverflow.com");
});
```

It doesn't work.

I agree with you. Using jQuery to change a link is pointless. For me, it was just a way to know how to use jQuery properly.

My purpose was to learn what script could work and where to put it properly.

I want to use jQuery because I want to use Featherlight and link to an open lightbox making sure the page where the page where my lightbox is called is loaded in the background. And for what I understood I could manage it using jQuery.

But it looks like I can't even call simple jQuery scripts. I have to convert it to JavaScript.

Well, that's something I'm going to learn and try.

Thank you to you all

Lise

Answer (score 0):

I get back to you because I found another solution to solve my problem **AND** use jQuery script.

I placed

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

inside the php tag before 'head' in the index.php of my template

```
<?php

/**
 * @package   Astroid Framework
 * @author    JoomDev https://www.joomdev.com
 * @copyright Copyright (C) 2009 - 2020 JoomDev.
 * @license https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPLv2 or Later
 */
// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
defined('_ASTROID') or die('Please install and activate <a href="https://www.astroidframework.com/" target="_blank">Astroid Framework</a> in order to use this template.');

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . "/helper.php")) {
   require_once __DIR__ . "/helper.php"; // Template's Helper
}

JHtml::_('jquery.framework');

$document = Astroid\Framework::getDocument(); // Astroid Document
// Output as HTML5
$this->setHtml5(true);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>">

<head>
...
</head>

</html>
```

This way, I can use jQuery scripts directly inside my custom JS file monjs.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#ali").attr("href","https://stackoverflow.com");
});
```

Comment: Please understand that when you post an answer, you are not "getting back to someone"; nor should you attempt to reply to another answer with a new answer.  Please take our [tour] to understand that Stack Exchange communities are not designed like old forums.  Here, there is only one question and potentially multiple answers.  Answers must not be posted as a way of communicating to another answer.